# How to set a variable in ObjectSelect criteria params in DoctrineModule

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'd like to know how to set a variable in ObjectSelect criteria params.
My code is as follow:

```
$this->add(
   array(
     'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
     'name' => 'shop',
     'attributes' => array(
         'class' => 'chosen-select form-control'
      ),

      'options' => array(
          'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
          'target_class' => '\Godana\Entity\Shop',
          'property' => 'name',
          'label' => 'Shop',
          'label_attributes' => array(
              'class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label',
          ),
          'find_method' => array(
               'name' => 'findBy',
               'params' => array(
                   'criteria' => array('owner' => $this->shopOwner),
               ),
          ),

       ),
    )
);
```

and it returns empty value but if I use a static value like 'criteria' => array('owner' => 1) it returns data from my db.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be $this->shopOwner->getId() ?